# How to read a usb serial port in JAVA?

Tags: java, api, serial-port, javax.comm, jssc

I add some detail to my question. 
I receive on my Xbee device a flow of GPS coordinates but I'm unable to read and stock these data on a buffer.

My Xbee device is connected to my laptop on a usb serial port, that's why I want to create a program java to read and use my data flow sending by the serial port.

I'm searching on internet some code example or tutorials , without enought advices for my understanding, or I just find some dead projects.

I found that it's possible to use jssc library or javax.comm (but I can't download the javax.zip on sun). Do you know an other better USB API ? Could you help me to understand how I can manage to read and stock my Flow of GPS cordinate ?

Answer (score 4):

Forget abut USB, it acts as transparent bridge. What you need is a way to read from the serial port. `javax.comm` is not (officially) available any more. I have been successfull dealing with the arduino serial port with the [`RXTX`](http://mfizz.com/oss/rxtx-for-java) library.

First make sure you see the serial port on your dev machine. This might require to install a driver. Then use a terminal program to connect to the serial port.

Once this is working go on and get `RXTX` working.

Just in case: You can have only one connection at a time. Make sure that only one of IDE, terminal programm and `RXTX` is connecting to the serial port at the same time.

Comment: OK thank you,
and you worked with arduino IDE ? I'm not sure to understand, I have a xbib-u-dev so I'm not sure I can worked with the arduino serial port ?